# How to add a tuple with an inputted name to a list

Tags: python, list, input, tuples

this pyhton code...

```
food = {}
drinks = {}
others = {}

menu = [food,drinks,others]
```

So I want to create a function that recieves an input with a category that that user would like to add to the menu list. How can i make this passing this same input name to the dictionary? I would like my output to be like this

```
menu = [food,drink,others,inputted_name]
```

of course inputted name being also a dictionary with its name being the "inputted name"

Comment: the categories are dictionaries and the menu is the list of those dictionaries, now you want to have a function that adds a dictionary to that list?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, perhaps you want a nested dictionary? `{'inputted_name':['food':{},'drink':{},'others':{}...]}` or similar?

Comment: `menu.append(inputted_name)` ? But if you want to use user's input then better use dictionary `menu = {"food": {}, "drinks": {}, "others":{}}` and then `menu[inputted_name] = {...}`

Comment: BTW: you could also keep categories as dictiory `categories  = {"food": {}, "drinks": {}, "others":{}}` and then you can use user's input to do get category and add to menu `menu[inputted_name] = categories[inputted_name]`.